# Row sums for searching vector over data frame with conditions

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a vector `v` and searches is over some data frame `df`. The function which does this is

`` (1) df[rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, v)) > 0, ] ``

this does the trick, except that it does only exact matches, and I would like to use this to perform a search over a range of values (+/- 1). I tried:

`(2) df[rowSums(sapply(df > v-1 & df < v+1)) > 0,]`

For example right now I have something like:

`df <- data.frame(c(A, B, C, D, E),c(191.1, 124.2, 200.0, 203.0, 192.3), c(193.1, 126.2, 202.0, 204.2, 199.2))` and `v <- c(191.1, 200.0, 192.4, 126.9, 205.1, 199.0, 169.0, 138.3, 200.1, 692.1, 1200.0)`. So the vector `v` has `length(v) > length(df)`.

My expected output when using function (1) above is:

`A     191.1     193.1`

`C     200.0     202.0`

Using (2) I would like to return rows which fall between any values +/- 1 in vector `v`.

Comment: Can you please show a small example with expected output

Comment: Yes, I just made that edit to the question.

Comment: Your first column is not numeric, so it needs to be excluded from, the comparison

Comment: Okay sure that is not a problem, I can fix that after.

Comment: I checked your expected.  and was looking at the other columns.  Are you filtering by either or all.  If it is all, then none of them meets the condition and either gets all the rows

Comment: Please check `Reduce(`|`, lapply(v, function(x) rowSums(df[-1] > (x -1) & df[-1] < (x + 1)) > 0))#
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`
`Reduce(`&`, lapply(v, function(x) rowSums(df[-1] > (x -1) & df[-1] < (x + 1)) > 0))#
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: Can you please check your example because the condition is not giving the expected

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the anonymous function.  Here, the `length` of 'v' is not clear.  If it is the same length as the number of rows of 'df'

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, function(x)  x > v-1 &  x < v+1)) > 0,]
```

---

If the `vector` 'v'  is of different `length`, we may need a nested loop or may be

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(v, function(v1) rowSums(df > v1 -1 & df < v1 + 1) > 0)), ]
```

#### Update

Based on the example OP provided, may be this helps, but the input example and the conditions are not matching with expected

```
df[rowSums(Reduce(`|`, Map(function(vx, vy) df[-1] > vx &
     df[-1] < vy, v -1, v + 1))) == 2,]
#  v1    v2    v3
#1  A 191.1 193.1
#5  E 192.3 199.2
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(3, 4, 2, 5, 10 ),
   col2 = c(1, 3, 4, 25, 6), col3 = c(3, 1, 4, 2, 9))
v <- 1:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are trying to do :

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df[-1], function(y) sapply(y, function(x) 
           any(x > v-1 &  x < v+1)))) == 2, ]
```

This will select rows where both the columns have at least one value in `v` which is in the range.